# Deploy Windows applications in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Hi I'm using QT Creator 2.4.1 based on Qt 4.7.4 on Win 7 (64 Bit)

I would like to know a simple way to deploy my Qt GUI application to windows. It needs to be simple because I've been teaching my students to program GUI apps in Qt and now I want to show them how to deploy. (I now realise my error in not checking this prior to starting the course, however I assumed it would simple).

I've looked at Qt site requiring static linking:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/deployment-windows.html

and using NISI to package and deploy the application.

None of these options are simple enough to show my students. I would be keen to know how other people deploy windows applications using Qt Creator. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Not deadsimple either, but worth a look: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtifw-1.3/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that copying the required dlls (one per each module, used plugins and two for MinGW runtime or if you use Visual Studio install the runtime for the used VS version) is simple enough for students that learn how to code. And regarding NSIS (i assume that NISI is a typo - or at least i haven't heard of it) you can use a gui project for it, like this [one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnsis/) (i used one once, but i don't remember if that was the one) anyway you can google for some and play and see what you like or... a little nsis scripting can't hurt your students that much ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I'll go with just copying the dll's to the directory. I'll give NSIS (not NISI) a miss because it still requires grabbing all required dll's anyways, could be wrong! I just wish that Qt Creator could do this within the IDE!!!

Comment: Well then, maybe a good idea is to create and work with the students on a project that creates a gui for nsis, it can even be a Creator plugin.

Comment: I'd like to add that the included NSIS examples are very helpful, although you'll have to really dig through a bit - in any case, I'd recommend using it

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your question is "I'd like to know how others do it", here's my answer:

I develop the applications in Linux (it's the more convenient OS for development,) and then cross compile to Windows using [MXE](http://mxe.cc), which gives me statically linked *.exe files that have everything they need linked into them (Qt itself, as well as any other libraries I'm using.)

Probably not a very useful answer, other than the suggestion that using Linux for teaching software development might actually be a good idea. It's a very developer-centric platform and much easier to work with in that regard.